# Why is Docker's IP not working in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: docker, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge can't reach Docker's IP `192.168.99.100`. It works fine for other browsers. But localhost works for Edge. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: Its for "security reasons" check this post about it https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/16262643/

Comment: i check this post already. localhost(127.0.0.1) working fine but virtual machine ip (192.168.99.100) not working yet. I also add ip to allowed local intranet

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow steps below may help you to solve the issue.

(1) Open Edge.

(2) Type 'about:flags' in address bar.

(3) Check the option for 'Allow Localhost Loopback'.

(4) Restart the Edge and try to visit localhost.

[image]

If that not works then try to open command prompt as an administrator and run command below and try again.

```html
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.Windows.Spartan_cw5n1h2txyewy

or

CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -p=S-1-15-2-3624051433-2125758914-1423191267-1740899205-1073925389-3782572162-737981194
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running docker with virtual box you can apply this port forwarding solution:

1. Open Virtual box
2. Select your Docker Virtual machine
3. Click..Settings in the toolbar
4. Click..Network
5. Click..Advanced
6. Click Port Forwarding
7. Click the Plus sign
8. Enter...Name="Example port forward", Protocol=TCP, Host IP=127.0.0.1, Host IP=8080, Guest IP , Guest port=8080
9. Press..ok
10. Press..ok again
11. Finally open your edge browser at: http://localhost:8080/

Reference: https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/